# What is wrong with this Ordered List? AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm following the tutorial from [Interactive Python](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/BasicDS/linkedlists.html) to make an Ordered List in Python. My code looks like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def setData(self, newdata):
        self.data = newdata

    def setNext(self, newnext):
        self.next = newnext

class OrderedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def search(self, item):
        found = False
        stop = False
        current = self.head
        while current != None and not found and not stop:
            if current.getData() == item:
                found = True
            elif current.getData() > item:
                stop = True
            else:
                current = current.getNext()

        return found

    def add(self, item):
        previous = None
        current = self.head
        stop = False
        while current != None and not stop:
            if current.getData() > item:
                stop = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.getNext()

        temp = Node(item)       
        if previous == None:
            temp.setNext(self.head)
            self.head = temp
        else:
            temp.setNext(current)
            previous.setNext(temp)

    def remove(self, item):
        previous = None
        current = self.head
        found = False
        while not found:
            if current.getData() == item:
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.getNext()

        if previous == None:
            self.head = current.getNext()
        else:
            previous.setNext(current.getNext)

    def update(self, olddata, newdata):
        self.remove(olddata)
        self.add(newdata)

    def display(self):
        current = self.head
        print("The contents of this list are: ", end='')
        print()
        while current:
            print(current.data)
            current = current.getNext()

myList = OrderedList()
myList.add(5)
myList.add(25)
myList.add(30)
myList.remove(25)
myList.display()
myList.update(5, 30)
myList.display()
```

It keeps telling me my variable current is a function and doesn't have the atrributes for a Node. How can I fix it and what am I doing wrong?

The output I get:

```
The contents of this list are: 
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 92, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 88, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 80, in display
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: Post the exact error message please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigned the `Node.getNext` *method* to your `Node.next` attribute in your `OrderedList.remove` method:

```
else:
    previous.setNext(current.getNext)
```

You can see this by introspecting your `myList.head` attribute:

```
>>> vars(myList.head)
{'data': 5, 'next': <bound method Node.getNext of <__main__.Node object at 0x105a726d8>>}
```

You wanted to *call* the method there; otherwise you'll end up with `Node.getNext()` returning that method references rather than a `Node()` instance.

Fixing that mistake, your code appears to work:

```
The contents of this list are: 
5
30
The contents of this list are: 
30
30
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it. I can't believe how such a small error broke my code so easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the recursive structure of this so-constructed ordered list. So, this is maybe just a typo - correct it like this:

```
class OrderedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node(None)
```

then there is one more typo left, that can be easily found.

Code snipped to comment below:

```
def remove(self, item):
    previous = None
    current = self.head
    found = False
    while not found:
        if current.getData() == item:
            found = True
        else:
            previous = current
            current = current.getNext()
            if current == None: 
                print "Element not found"
                return
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why the code works without using the Node object?

Comment: The difference becomes clear when adding the above mentioned lines to your `remove` function and only running the test-code `myList = OrderedList();
myList.remove(25)`